# Pandas dataframe only reading first value, NaN for everything else

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I am attempting to read a csv with pandas and then insert into a SQL table. I am reading the data from the csv correctly when I print(data), but once I add it into the dataframe it is only reading the very first column, and is inserting NaN for every other value in the csv. Code and output below;

```
data = pd.read_csv (localFilePath)
print(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Date','EECode','LastName','FirstName', \
           'HomeDepartmentCode','HomeDepartmentDesc','PayClass','InPunchTime', \
           'OutPunchTime','DepartmentCode','DepartmentDesc','JobCodesCode', \
           'JobCodesDesc','TeamCode','TeamDesc','EarnCode'])
print(df)

for row in df.itertuples():
    SQLInsert = ('''
                INSERT INTO [Reporting].[dbo].[Paycom_Missing_Punch] 
                (Date, EECode, LastName, FirstName, HomeDepartmentCode, 
                HomeDepartmentDesc, PayClass, InPunchTime, OutPunchTime, 
                DepartmentCode, DepartmentDesc, JobCodesCode, JobCodesDesc, 
                TeamCode, TeamDesc, EarnCode)
                VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
                '''
                )
     args = row.Date, row.EECode, row.LastName, row.FirstName, \
                row.HomeDepartmentCode, row.HomeDepartmentDesc, row.PayClass, row.InPunchTime, \
                row.OutPunchTime, row.DepartmentCode, row.DepartmentDesc, row.JobCodesCode, \
                row.JobCodesDesc, row.TeamCode, row.TeamDesc, row.EarnCode
                          
    #print(SQLInsert) 
    #print(args)
    cursor.execute(SQLInsert, args)     
conn.commit()
```

output when I print(data);

```
         Date  EE Code  ...               Team Desc Earn Code
0  01/21/2021     1435  ...             Indiana DWD       NaN
1  01/21/2021     1435  ...             Indiana DWD       NaN
2  01/22/2021     1180  ...             Supervisors       NaN
3  01/21/2021     1664  ...  Technical Support Desk       NaN
4  01/21/2021     1078  ...             Supervisors       NaN
```

output once I add it to the dataframe;

```
         Date  EECode  LastName  ...  TeamCode  TeamDesc  EarnCode
0  01/21/2021     NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN
1  01/21/2021     NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN
2  01/22/2021     NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN
3  01/21/2021     NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN
4  01/21/2021     NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

I assume the problem is how I am passing the values to the dataframe, but from everything I have read or seen, the way I am doing it looks correct.

Comment: Not sure if that is the case, but your args seems to be outside of the loop?

Comment: That's a formatting issue from the copy/paste to stack... I updated it

Comment: Changing it to data.itertuples() got me the same result, where it is reading the first column and inserting NaN for every other column. Is it possible it's reading the delimiter wrong, and that's why it's only getting the first value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the way you're doing the `df`. You're creating the dataframe first with your `data`. Then you're trying to create another dataframe of it, using names that don't exist. To fix your problem simply do this:

```
>>> col_names = ['Date','EECode','LastName','FirstName', \
           'HomeDepartmentCode','HomeDepartmentDesc','PayClass','InPunchTime', \
           'OutPunchTime','DepartmentCode','DepartmentDesc','JobCodesCode', \
           'JobCodesDesc','TeamCode','TeamDesc','EarnCode']

>>> df = pd.read_csv(localFilePath)
>>> df.columns = col_names
```

Comment: when I do that way I get the error "Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name", but if I do it like this; df = pd.read_csv(localFilePath, names=col_names) I get an error about trying to convert a date from a sting, so it looks like it fixed the actual problem and I have a new problem.

Comment: In case anyone reads this, the new problem was that I had to explicitly name a column as a date since pandas was reading it as a string, which I did with this; df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

Comment: You can do this when you're loading it using `parse_dates`. Check the manual [read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)